# PYAUTOGUI.HOTKEY

Tags: python, pyautogui

I know that the most usefull tool to create and manipulate workbook/paste are Pandas or Openpyxl.

My problem is with TOTVS: I find a table in its program and I need to copy to a DB.

I was trying going through an entire column by just using `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift','down')`. But, instead of selecting the entire column, it goes just to the end. With none selection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We need to see enough code that we can actually re-create the problem for ourselves, and understand what you see. Also, it isn't clear what "TOTVS" is, and I have no idea why you want to use `pyautogui` for this problem. It sounds like you want to control the mouse and keyboard to work with another spreadsheet program? But **why**? Why not just use pandas/openpyxl like you said?

Comment: "English is not my 1st language and I really putted effort trying to express my problem. In case you didn't understand, let me know." In case it helps, Stack Overflow is also available in [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), [Japanese](https://jp.stackoverflow.com) and [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: you really need to give more detail if you want help.

Comment: Have you tried:
`
from pyautogui import *
keyDown("Ctrl")
keyDown("shift")
keyDown("down")
keyUp("down")
keyUp("shift")
keyUp("ctrl")
`
?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed similar issue on my side.

To me it looks like PyAutoGUI possibly has some issues with simulating pressing more than two non-alphanumeric buttons as hotkeys.

Let me clarify my experience:

My setup:

- Windows 10
- VS Code (latest)
- Chrome (latest)
- Python (3.10)
- PyAutoGUI (latest)

I tried to automate Chrome cache/cookies clearing using hotkeys CTRL + SHIFT + DEL combination:

```
import pyautogui, time

pyautogui.click(256,1056) # Chrome icon click
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(952,606) # click on Chrome empty page
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'delete')
```

Result: Visually `pyautogui.hotkey` command doesn't seem to be executed, Chrome cache/cookies clearing window isn't opened.

I had several theories on why it doesn't work properly (turned out they all are irrelevant):

1. Key naming is wrong -> tried all corresponding key names from this [official manual](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys).
2. `pyautogui.PAUSE` setting affects hotkeys action -> removed it from script.
3. PyAutoGUI isn't focused on Chrome, therefore hotkeys are sent to wrong app -> added extra click in a middle of empty Chrome page to make sure it is focused.
4. Windows confuses this hotkey combination with different one **before** everything is pressed -> changed all corresponding Windows hotkeys combinations.
5. This is just `pyautogui.hotkey` issue -> tried to workaround it using `pyautogui.hold` and `pyautogui.keyDown`

As a result for last one I've seen part of hotkeys combination working (CTRL + SHIFT was pressed).

For others result was the same as for initial script (cache/cookies clearing window isn't opened).

I finally tried to just open Windows task manager by CTRL + ALT + DEL combination. It doesn't work as well for me. Behavior is the same as one for Chrome script.

At the same time key combinations including alphanumeric keys inside Chrome (for example, CTRL + SHIFT + N) and outside it (CTRL + A) are working flawlessly, just as expected.

---

***UPD:*** I just found another approach, and I think it gives some clues.

I used [W3C online key event viewer](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html) to see keyboard input logs.

Here are results:

case 1:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrlleft', 'shiftleft', 'altleft')
```

keyboard input log:

[image: result for CTRL + SHIFT + ALT]

case 2:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrlleft', 'shiftleft', 'delete')
```

keyboard input log:

[image: result for CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE]

May anyone explain what happens in case 2 and why?